# Error distributing iOS app ITMS-9000

Tags: ios, xcode, signed

I have made a game using game maker and successfully got it exported to xcode 5 on my mac. I have also successfully played the game on my iphone, so the game does work quite well.

I do have the provisional profile, the certificates needed (developer and distribution). I only have my certificate once in my keychain.

I also created my app on the developer website where it is now ready for upload.

Whenever I try to upload I can select my app and it starts uploading, only after a short time I get the error:
ERROR ITMS-9000 The bundle "com.grown-apps.whopays" at bundle path payload/whopays.app is not signed using an apple submission certificate at softwareassets/softwareasset (MZITMSPsoftwareassetpackage)

But I have signed everything in xcode 5. I selected the distribution profile to sign with.

It doesn't matter how I try to upload, using application loader or xcode 5, I get the same error.

I have now tried for a WHOLE WEEK searching the internet, and I just now got to the end where I simply cannot stand this anymore. I have followed every video or text guide I could possibly find. I have found many people with the same issues both here and everywhere else, none of the solutions people came up with and worked for many just didn't work for me.
I am now sitting here at 3 in the morning almost bald from ripping off my hair in desperation in hoping that someone somewhere has ANY idea what I can try next, this really is my last cry for help. I have used more than 100 hours just researching on this problem and it has turned up nothing for me.

Please help me so I don't have to take the final step and throw my expensive mac out the window!

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem and just resolved it today. In order for me to get anything from Windows to the Mac via Game Maker Studio, I had set the certificates "Trust" setting in the Keychain Access to "Always Trust" for both the provision and the distribution.

HOWEVER, for the app store submission, I had to change the "Trust" setting back to "Use System Default" for both the certificates. Also the keys attached to the Certificates are always put on "Allow all applications to access this item" in the "Access Control" tab of the respective key, regardless of the Certificate "Trust" parameter. I hope this helps people in the same bind.